# JSON from Objective-C in Swift

Tags: objective-c, json, swift, ios8

Connected Objective-C classes to the project Swift, as it is written here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html

There's this code of the test project:
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
var locations:NSArray=[]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var jsonLoader:JSONLoader
    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://mechnikova.info/api/pic2.php?task=1")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
      self.locations = jsonLoader.locationsFromJSONFile(url)
    })

}
```

JSONLoader - Objective-C class. This class is connected normally, without errors.
Get an error indicating that the character "{" in the function dispatch_async:

**Variable 'jsonLoader' used before initialized**

Something is wrong in declaration variables.... Help please!

Comment: But I don't see any initialization of `jsonLoader` in your code so I guess it's `nil`... Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
var jsonLoader:JSONLoader = JSONLoadeer()
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use former methods such as objectForKey() or access a specific element in an array using square brackets. Examples can be found [at this link](http://nscurious.com/?p=94). Hope this will help you parse your json!